# Why do I get a parse exception

Tags: java, parseexception

this programe should subtract 2 days tare3 and tare4 . tare3  valued from current day (from system ) tare4 value from text file (element [3]) , when i parsed string (element[3]) to date (tare4) its give`me parseexception 
date saved in file looked like (Thu Jan 24 00:00:00 EET 2018)

```
package javaapplication3;        
import java.io.*;            `     `
import java.util.*;                  
import java.text.*;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {


 private  static String tare5 = new String();
  static String tare2 = new String ();

          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd MMM yyyy  ",Locale.ENGLISH );
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date tare4 =  new Date (); 
        tare5 = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
      Date  tare3 = dateFormat.parse(tare5);

          Scanner scanner;
         File Myfile =  new File("C:\\Users\\mido\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication3\\src\\javaapplication3\\products.txt");
       scanner = new Scanner (Myfile);


      while (scanner.hasNext()){

         String line = scanner.nextLine();
      StringTokenizer x = new StringTokenizer(line,"~");
         String [] element= new String [7]; 
         int counter = 0 ;

         while (x.hasMoreElements())
         {
          element[counter]=(String)x.nextElement();
         counter ++;

         }
          tare4 = dateFormat.parse(element[3]);

       if (tare4.getTime()>= tare3.getTime() )
       {
        System.out.println(element[1]+"is expired");
       }
       else {
         long def = tare3.getTime()- tare4.getTime();
         System.out.println(element[1]+"has"+def+"to expire");}
        }

        }
```

The stacktrace is as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20/10/2015 " at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357) at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:51)
```

Comment: it would be good to have the stacktrace as well @Muhamed Hussam

Comment: it is not working :\

Comment: i meant add the exception/error message faced

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20/10/2015 "
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
 at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:51)

Comment: @nullpointer are you knowing where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input `20/10/2015` doesn't meet the cases to fall under the `dateFormat`. You might want to change

`SimpleDateFormat(" dd MMM yyyy  ",Locale.ENGLISH )`

to

`SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH )`

Comment: Thx this error is removed but last question why the new output is

Comment: 10is expired
50has27388800000to expire
40has19702800000to expire
35is expired
49is expired
98is expired
76is expired
14is expired
99is expired

Comment: you might want to specify the details of output you expect in that case

Comment: there is function subtract dates ?

Comment: aha i want specific output 
let says the program will subtract 24/11/2016 -24/10/2015
i want the output  "1 year and 1 month and 0 days to expire . did u undertand me ?

Comment: `d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
   d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

   //in milliseconds
   long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

   long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
   long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
   long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
   long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

   System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
   System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
   System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
   System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");
` should help you

Comment: this code is for min hour second i want year month day ,